# Maximum vector value function problems

Tags: c, function, vector

The function I'm making is supposed to return to the maximum value in a vector, and I'm stumped as to why it's not working, here is the code:

```
float max(float vec[], int len) {
    int i;
    float max;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (vec[i] > max) {
            max = vec[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: yea, `max` is uninitialized, what should it be upon the first comparison?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you are not supposed to apologise for terribly formatting the code, just learn Markdown, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` is uninitialized and using uninitialized variables leads to undefined behavior.

```
float max = vec[0];// Initialize max before using it
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize local variable

```
float max;
```

You could do it the following way

```
float max = vec[0];
```

Also the function has a problem when the second parameter is either equal to 0 or is a negative value.

The general approach is to return the index of the maximum element and in the caller to compare the returned index with the value of the second parameter. If they are equal then the array is empty. Otherwise the index points to the maximum element.

So the function could be written the following way

```
size_t max_element( const float vec[], size_t len ) 
{
    size_t max = 0;
    size_t i = 1;

    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( vec[max] < vec[i] ) max = i;
    }

    return max;
}
```

and in the caller you could write

```
float vec[] = { /* some initializers */ };
size_t max = max_element( vec, sizeof( vec ) / sizeof( *vec ) );

printf( "The maximum value is &f for element with index %zu\n", vec[max], max );
```